# Python Code to image subtract consecutive images

Tags: python, image, subtraction

I have a bunch of images named `0.jpg`, `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, etc. I am trying to create a code to subtract consecutive images. I have the subtraction code down, but I can't seem to figure out how to loop through the folder that has all these images to do consecutive image subtractions such that: 0.jpg - 1.jpg, 1.jpg - 2.jpg, 2.jpg - 3.jpg, etc.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from numpy import asarray
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import os

directory ='/home/pi/Desktop/tryy'

filelist = os.listdir(directory)
filelists = sorted(filelist,key=lambda x:int(os.path.splitext(x)[0]))

for i in filelists:
    i = 0
    imgX = cv2.imread(filelists[i])
    imgY = cv2.imread(filelists[i+1])
    imgZ = cv2.absdiff(imgX, imgY)
    
    thresh = cv2.threshold(imgZ,30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
    data = asarray(thresh)
    print(data)

#Movement Output
    Maximum = np.max(data)
    print(Maximum)

    if Maximum == 255:
        print("Movement")
    else:
        print("No Movement")
    i= i+1
```

Comment: Could you include your code, and what you've tried so far?

Comment: I added an image of the code into the description above. It is linked to the part that says "enter image description here"

Comment: Please add the code as text instead

Comment: Just added it as text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function like this:

```py
for x, y in zip(filelists[:-1], filelists[1:]):
    imgX = cv2.imread(os.path.join(directory, x)).astype(np.float_)
    imgY = cv2.imread(os.path.join(directory, y)).astype(np.float_)
    imgZ = cv2.absdiff(imgX, imgY)
```

Note that if `directory` is not located in the current directory, you must pass the full path of the images to `cv2.imread`. Besides, you should convert the images to `float_` in order to avoid integer overflow/underflow when adding/subtracting `np.uint8` images.

Comment: It didn't work. Do you think that the image file is unreadable once it becomes part of a list? For all the maximum values of the image subtractions, the output is "none". It should give me either a value of 0 or 255.

Comment: I have just figured out why my code didn't worked. Please, see my edited answer.